# Does the number of times the sitemap has been updated affect SEO positively?

Tags: seo, sitemap

Does the number of sitemaps on Webmaster Tools affect the Google ranking at all? My website contains two different feeds of constant weekly updates and was wondering whether I should consider submitting a sitemap every week.

Comment: If you are changing URL of pages frequently then only it will help to change sitemap. Otherwise it does not require to update sitemap.

Answer (score 2):

Sitemaps have almost no effect on rankings.   You don't need a sitemap to have your pages rank well.   In fact, it has been suggested that using sitemaps is a red herring.  You instead should be spending time making sure your site links to all your content.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).

The only time that I can imagine that submitting fresh sitemaps regularly would help would be for news sites.   For news articles, freshness is key to rankings.   Google recognizes that for news related queries users want the latest results.  These [queries deserve freshness](http://moz.com/blog/whiteboard-friday-query-deserves-freshness).   In that case, keeping your sitemap up to date with changes could allow Googlebot to see your fresh content more readily and your site to rank better for news queries that need fresh content.

Comment: Bingo! You are right in that sitemaps do not effect SEO however, there is the secondary effect that it helps Google and Bing find your fresh pages better and faster which will effect SEO somewhat which you mention. People often forget the secondary effects and go for the absolute answer. As well, I do think for most sites a sitemap is necessary, but it does not hurt either. There are very real cases where using a sitemap is absolutely necessary. I just cannot stand that SEO experts are pushing a sitemap as a step in the SEO process. It is misleading and causes many spinning wheels.